# Asking for confirmation before changing the radio option

Tags: vue.js

How do I ask the user for a confirmation before changing the option in a radio button using `Vue.js`?

Something like *Are you sure?* would be fine.

Comment: First, add click event on radio button, then execute `event.preventDefault()`. Next, write `Are you sure` or other logics in the click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following DOM structure:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="radio"/>
</div>
```

you can bind a `@change` directive to the radio button with a method implementing the expected "*Are you sure?*" confirmation popup. So you can enrich the above mentioned DOM structure like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="radio" @change="showConfirm"/>
</div>
```

And in the Vue instance you can define the expected confirmation method, for example:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  methods: {
    showConfirm: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let checkedRadio = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
      event.target.checked = checkedRadio;
    }
  }
})
```

Here you find the [working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PgMrow).

Comment: @RobertoPezzali the example has been improved in order to satisfy your needs.